# How to test an HTML page with jQuery DOM manipulations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, npm

I was asked to develop an HTML page with jQuery DOM manipulations - e.g., when I click the submit button, a success/error message is displayed - and to test them. I'm used to do such a things with Angular and Jasmine, but I really have no clue on how to do it with plain javascript and jQuery.

I have already tried using Jasmine and QUnit, but I receive the following error: `$ is not defined`.

---

I do not want to use jQuery for test the page. I want to use Jasmine (or a similar testing framework) to test the page and the way jQuery manipulate it.

---

This is the code of one of my failing attempt:

```
it("should display a notification", function () {
    const fs = require('fs');
    const jsdom = require('jsdom');
    const jquery = require('jquery');
    fs.readFile('index.html', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        const dom = new jsdom.JSDOM(data);
        const $ = jquery(dom.window);
        expect($('.notification.is-hidden').length).toBe(1);
        $('.button').click();
        expect($('.notification.is-hidden').length).toBe(0);
    });
});
```

On the button click, jQuery remove the `is-hidden` class...but the second `expect` fails anyway and I don't know why.

Comment: Did you include jquery on your page?

Comment: Even fixing the missing jQuery include, "how to test" is too broad of a question

Comment: Also why use jQuery for testing when that's not what it's intended for.  Jasmine, a testing library, is a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the `$ is not defined` error is because you are not including jQuery in your page. 
if isn't already present, add jQuery to the `<head>` section of your html file.
Example:

`<srcipt src="cdn/link/or/path/to/jQuery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`